# SpyMemcached and Memcached: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

```
[2011-08-29 10:05:09.132]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
[2011-08-29 10:05:54.590]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
[2011-08-29 10:07:36.333]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
[2011-08-29 10:08:44.030]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
[2011-08-29 10:08:49.655]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
[2011-08-29 10:08:55.871]ALERT: SpyMemcached.getInstance(memcache.job) is invalid! check memcached.property .
```

I got lots of lines above in my log file. And i have no idea why this happened. 
I am using Spymemcached 2.5 over JDK 1.6 update 23 on a x86_64 GNU/Linux server and  memcached 1.4.5 on another similar Linux server. Any one has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpyMemcached doesn't have a class called SpyMemcached and doesn't have that error message.  That sounds like something in your code.